# MonitoringForRegion did not give output?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios4, core-location

CLLocationManager's  property regionMonitoringEnabled is not working in my project? it always  returns false value . i am using iphone 3gs.please tell whether i have to use iPhone 4 or not?I am following the code from the URL  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665155/startmonitoringforregion-not-working)

Comment: I think that should work on the 3GS. Do you get the permission dialog asking to allow the app to use your location? Does the start updating location method work?

Answer (score 1):

Region monitoring is only available on iPhone 4 because it requires a specific feature in the baseband.